# File Upload form using php

Tags: php, html

i'm working on app that takes a shot from the camera and upload the picture to the server so this is my code:-

```
<form id="theform" action="upload.php" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return myFunction();" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input id="file" name="uploadedFile" onchange="uptoserver();" style="display:none;"type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <button type="submit"  class="btn wbtn border rounded-pill" style="font-family:Hana; font-size:32px;">
            <img src="style\image\camera.png" width="64" />&nbsp;تصوير النمودج&nbsp;
          </button>&nbsp;
          </div>
          </form>
```

and upload.php :-

```
<?php 
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "جاري إضافة الملف  ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']). 
    " إلى جدول ملف إكسل";
   echo "<script>document.write(readfile(\"".$target_path."\"));</script>";
   $stringPath = $target_path; //PASSING NAME PARAM
    // how can i pass the Name to prepare.php
    printf($stringPath);
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

the problem is that this upload script is uploading the picture but its corrupted file with size of 0mb so how can i fix this problem

Comment: PHP and Javascript/DOM events execute in entirely different contexts. And have few and limited channels to deliver information between the two contexts. Read my explanation on another question for more about that, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022099/how-to-make-the-value-stored-in-the-php-session-update-with-the-ajax-submission/72023066#72023066 .

Comment: This: `echo "<script>document.write(readfile(\"".$target_path."\"));</script>";` followed by `printf($stringPath);` creates a string that, if properly called for, gets sent from the server to the browser by way of HTTP. If the browser calls *upload.php* by loading the page you leave the current page and only load that string in the browser. If the browser calls *upload.php* by way of [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), the page remains but you need to use Javascript to capture the STRING and do something with it.

Comment: This `action="upload.php" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); ...` prevents the form from being submitted to *upload.php* conventionally. What is the code for `myFunction()` and `uptoserver()` and `readfile()`.

Comment: Javascript [FileReader](https://javascript.info/file) only handles files *on the client* provided through a Javascript File or Blob object, or an `input type="file"` element, or a [drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) process.

Comment: I recommend checking the `$_FILES['uploadedFile']['error']` parameter before trying to move the file with `move_uploaded_file`. Maybe you will find your problem here. Also you should check `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'])` before moving. And third maybe you want to define a max file size which is smaller then the PHP.INI default of your server.

Comment: You might find this page helpful: [How to use HTML5 to capture a camera image](https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/How-to-use-HTML5-to-capture-a-camera-image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems with your code...

`onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); ...`

...prevents the form from submitting the file provided by `<input type="file" ...` to the form `action` target: *upload.php* conventionally, such as clicking the `submit` button.

~

```
echo "..." . basename( $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']) . "...";
echo "<script>document.write(readfile(\"".$target_path."\"));</script>";
$stringPath = $target_path; //PASSING NAME PARAM
printf($stringPath);
```

...your *upload.php* file simply writes a string that, if properly called for, gets sent from the server to the browser by way of HTTP.

NO Javascript is executed at this point.

If the browser calls upload.php by loading the page, you leave the current page and only load that string in the browser. If the browser calls upload.php by way of [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch), the page remains but you need to use Javascript to capture the STRING and do something with it.

~

```
echo "<script>document.write(readfile(\"".$target_path."\"));</script>";
```

In the PHP file, on the server, you are writing a string of Javascript code, which is sent as text to the browser to be executed there later. The browsers gets something like:

```
<script>document.write(readfile("uploads/filename.png"));</script>
```

It's okay to use PHP to send a Javascript string to the browser—however the problem is you're providing a file path *on the server*. Once the Javascript string gets to the browser and evaluated it does not have access to the server file and directory structure, such as: `uploads/filename.png`

Since you're attempting to execute a Javascript function named `readfile(...)` it appears you're trying to use Javascript [FileReader](https://javascript.info/file) to access the file uploaded to the server, but FileReader only handles files *on the client*, and provided through a Javascript File or Blob object, or an `input type="file"` element, or a [drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) process.

---

Keep in mind that PHP executes on the server, and only text gets sent to the browser. The browser then receives the text from the server and processes and renders it.

The PHP context on the server cannot execute Javascript, and the browser context (Javascript/DOM events) on the client cannot execute PHP.

You only have a *text channel* between the two. And the *text channel* is only invoked by a page load, or without a page load by using [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch). If you use XHR or Fetch you then need to use Javascript to handle the text received back from the server.

---

To take a photo, upload it to the server, and display the photo on the page, without reloading the page:

*camera.html*

```
<input type="file" id="campic" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

<script>

var campic = document.querySelector("#campic");

campic.onchange = function () {
  var file = campic.files[0];
  upload(file);
  displayAsImage(file);
};

function upload (file) {
  var form = new FormData(),
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  form.append('image', file);
  xhr.open('post', 'upload.php', true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.send(form);
}

function displayAsImage (file) {
  var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file),
      img = document.createElement('img');

  img.onload = function () {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(imgURL);
  };

  img.src = imgURL;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
</script>
```

*upload.php*

```
<?php 

$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']); 

if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path) ) {
    echo "File uploaded.";
} 
else {
    echo "Error uploading the file.";
}

?>
```

Get more information on this approach here: [How to use HTML5 to capture a camera image](https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/How-to-use-HTML5-to-capture-a-camera-image) .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to handle upload file

```
<?php
  
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST')
  {
      echo "Empty data, please select file";
      die;
  }

  if (!isset($_FILES["fileupload"]))
  {
      echo "Wrong data struct";
      die;
  }

  if ($_FILES["fileupload"]['error'] != 0)
  {
    echo "Uploaded data error";
    die;
  }
  $target_dir    = "uploads/";
  $target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileupload"]["name"]);
  $allowUpload   = true;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $maxfilesize   = 800000;
  $allowtypes    = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"]);
      if($check !== false)
      {
          //
      }
      else
      {
          echo "This's not image file.";
          $allowUpload = false;
      }
  }

  if (file_exists($target_file))
  {
      echo "File already exist, don't allow overwrite";
      $allowUpload = false;
  }
  if ($_FILES["fileupload"]["size"] > $maxfilesize)
  {
      echo "Please upload file less than $maxfilesize (bytes).";
      $allowUpload = false;
  }

  if (!in_array($imageFileType,$allowtypes ))
  {
      echo "Only allow file type: JPG, PNG, JPEG, GIF";
      $allowUpload = false;
  }

  if ($allowUpload)
  {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
      {
          echo "File ". basename( $_FILES["fileupload"]["name"]). " uploaded success.";

      }
      else
      {
          echo "Error when upload file.";
      }
  }
  else
  {
      echo "Error upload, may be large filesize, or wrong file type...";
  }
?>
```

Comment: You have added extensive file upload validation—nice to see, *however* the core functionality of your answer and the question is the same—from your answer: `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))`, from the question: `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))` . How does that solve the problem?

Comment: I think that problem might be when uploading the file, so I added a validation to control the file being uploaded.