# I can not to get the POST value from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to get the value from ajax with post in php, but this is not working, here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deletarPerson(id_person) {
        let pag = "<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__DIR__) . 'admin/'; ?>";
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: pag + "/config.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {
                id_person: id_person
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(result) {
                <?php
                    $aux = $_POST['id_person'];
                ?>
                alert('<?php echo $aux ?>')
            },
        })
    }
</script>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: You're able to read `$_POST['id_person']` in your `config.php` file, where the AJAX request is sent to.

Comment: I don't see where you use `result` in the ajax `success` function. `result` is where you get something back from your PHP file on the server. You may not realize the distinct execution contexts between PHP on the server, and Javascript on the client. I wrote a detailed answer addressing this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022099/how-to-make-the-value-stored-in-the-php-session-update-with-the-ajax-submission/72023066#72023066

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript ajax code:

```
function deletarPerson(id_person) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/echo.php", // <-- sending to echo.php on the server
                          // ...use whatever PHP file, on the server, 
                          // you need to get the necessary information
        method: "post",
        data: {
            id_person: id_person
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result) // <-- now use Javascript and the result variable,
                          // which is text sent back from the server,
                          // and do what you need to with it on the client
        },
    })
}
```

...and your PHP file:

```
<!-- echo.php -->
<?php

$aux = $_POST['id_person'];
echo $aux; // <-- whatever is echo'ed or print'ed in this file 
           // gets sent back to the server as text 
           // and is loaded in the Javascript result variable

// OR you can actually get some useful information from the server 
// and send that back instead

?>
```

Read more about the distinct executions contexts between [PHP on the server and Javascript/HTML/CSS... on the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022099/how-to-make-the-value-stored-in-the-php-session-update-with-the-ajax-submission/72023066#72023066).