# Pass variable in HTML ID to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I passed a variable to html via JS. this variable is now stored in the html ID "dialog_title". How can I pass the variable now to php to work with it?

id from here

```
function dialogOeffnen(id) {
    //display ID
    document.getElementById("dialog_title").innerText = id;
    //open popup
    document.getElementById("loslegen-dialog").classList.add("sichtbar");
    document.getElementById("body-overlay").classList.add("sichtbar");
}
```

passed the id from JS to HTML to display it

`<h1 id="dialog_title"></h1>`

Comment: It's on the client side now. To work with it server side, you'll need to either submit it in a form or via ajax to a PHP page.

Comment: [Here's a lengthy explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72023066) why @mykaf writes "...you'll need to either submit it in a form or via ajax to a PHP page."

Answer (score -1):

use the $_GET or $_POST method via a form to send the data to PHP on the server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

to work with an id **value** use DOMDocument to read HTML

example:

```
<?php
```

// load URL with info in element **id=i_want_to_know**

```
$oDom = new DOMDocument;
$oDom->loadHTMLFile( 'https://www.example.url/change_me' );
```

// select element id="i_want_to_know"

```
$oDomElement = $oDom->getElementById( 'i_want_to_know' );
```

// get the value

```
$i_know = $oDomElement->nodeValue;

?>
```

to suppress warnings about HTML add:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

(see: https://www.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)

Comment: Please read the question again. As this variable was set using JS, it's not possible to read it through DomDocument